# Is there a word for someone who performs instrumentation?

Tags: word-request, nouns

Specifically where instrumentation means "the use or application of instruments (as for observation, measurement, or control)". Is there a word to describe someone who performs instrumentation?

I tried looking up `instrumentor`, for which I did not find anything, and `instrumentator`, which according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instrumentator) means

> one that arranges a musical score for performance by a specific group
>   of instruments

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but might [**music arranger**](https://www.careerexplorer.com/careers/music-arranger/) be the term you're looking for? The act itself could be ***instrumentation*** or ***arrangement***, but I'm not sure how much difference there might be between those two terms, for people in that business.

Comment: I've been a musician for 50 years and have never heard the term `instrumentator` in any musical sense whatsoever… no matter what Merriam Webster may say. You really need to define what you mean by "performs instrumentation" because an instrument is not only something musical, it could be computing, scientific or other measuring apparatus.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **instrumentation engineer** is what you're looking for.

This is from a training website:

> **What is an instrumentation engineer?**
>   Instrumentation Engineers are responsible for planning, installing, monitoring and maintaining control systems and machinery within manufacturing environments. ([source](https://www.getreskilled.com/what-is-an-instrumentation-engineer/))

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a single word, if it exists.